# Laravel upload file in different folder

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);

    $filename =  time() . '.jpg';
    $filepath = public_path('uploads/');

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $filepath.$filename);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], public_path('uploads/newfolder').$filename);

    echo $filepath.$filename;
}
```

How can I upload the same image into different folders.
I have tried the above code and it doesn't work in the other folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run `move_uploaded_file` twice for the same file because as it name says, it *moves* the file, so on the second run, the original file won't exist anymore.

You must copy the file:

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);

    $filename =  time() . '.jpg';
    $filepath = public_path('uploads/');

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $filepath.$filename);

    // Note that here, we are copying the destination of your moved file. 
    // If you try with the origin file, it won't work for the same reason.
    copy($filepath.$filename, public_path('uploads/newfolder').$filename);

    echo $filepath.$filename;
}
```

Comment: Well, while your code is technically correct, it hurts me by logic. I'd personally first copy from tmp source and then finally, move it (or unlink).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski It's the same thing. The number of disk operations will be exactly the same, the difference is basically your and my opinion. :-)

Comment: in this case. But it's matter of habbits. Imagine the setup where you copy to the location which is monitored and the other tools **move** the file further. Or worse, imagine the situation when such system is added **later**. temporary source file is **guaranteed** to  be there, so it by logic less error prone to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;    
public function upload(Request $request){
     $filename =  time() . '.jpg';
     $filepath = public_path('uploads/newfolder/');
     $file      = $request->file( "filename" );
     Storage::putFileAs( $filepath, $file, $filename );
     echo Storage::url( 'uploads/newfolder/'.$filename );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Try with copy upload folder image to new folder like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$imgUpload = File::copy(public_path().'/uploads/'. $filename, public_path().'/newfolder/'. $filename);
```